# Loading jQuery Asynchronously Seems Slower

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

A few weeks ago I started tinkering with the idea of loading jQuery asynchronously, mainly because we also use jQuery UI which is somewhat large. My thinking was that instead of loading three scripts (jQuery, jQuery UI, and my own scripts), which would each block parsing etc, I would instead load them all asynchronously. I do use the Google CDN for jQuery and jQuery UI, but I'm testing assuming a fresh cache, meaning the longest possible load time for the user.

My scripts depend on jQuery, and I can't count on asynchronous scripts to run in the order I want, so I use an interval to wait for jQuery to be available.

This all works perfectly fine.

The problem is that (to my surprise) the asynchronously loaded version of the page loads slower than the synchronous one, and I can't figure out why, or what I should do to improve it (if there's anything I can do at all).

I set up a test page to illustrate the problem, but I couldn't exactly get it working on jsfiddle (sorry). I ran all tests in Google Chrome. The basic idea is:

1. In various places, log the current seconds / milliseconds
2. include:

   - jQuery
   - jQueryUI
   - some html that will be modified when jQuery is ready
   - a bunch of images to slow down the page load (randomly pulled from google)
3. run the page, observe, and check the log notes in the console.

What I found is that when NOT loading asynchronously, the page visually loads quicker (the FOUC is very brief) and the logs confirm a faster load time, usually less than one second:

- Start Page Load at 3:290
- Start Main Script at 3:669
- End Page Load at 3:680
- Waiting for jQuery at 3:897
- jQuery Loaded at 3:898
- Document Ready at 3:898
- END Document Ready at 3:957

However, when loading asynchronously, the page has a much longer FOUC, and the logs confirm that jQuery is waiting longer for the document to be ready:

- Start Page Load at 52:460
- Start Main Script at 52:624
- End Page Load at 52:635
- Waiting for jQuery at 53:204
- Waiting for jQuery at 53:441
- jQuery Loaded at 53:441
- Document Ready at 54:652
- END Document Ready at 54:795

When loaded asynchronously, it seems like jQuery is waiting for the images to load before triggering doc ready, while normally it doesn't wait. Notice that the overall load time on the asynchronous version is over two seconds.

One other problem that I haven't tackled yet is that jQuery UI might load and run before jQuery. Because of the issues above, I haven't bothered with this one since it'll be a moot point if I don't switch to asynchronous loads in the first place.

Can anyone enlighten me? I must not understand something about how this all works.

Here's the source code, it uses PHP to switch between asynchronous and regular:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    var milliseconds = date.getMilliseconds();
    console.log("Start Page Load" + " at " + seconds + ":" + milliseconds);
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Testing Async jQuery</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"<?php if ( isset( $_REQUEST["async"] ) ) { ?> async defer<?php } ?>></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"<?php if ( isset( $_REQUEST["async"] ) ) { ?> async defer<?php } ?>></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    var milliseconds = date.getMilliseconds();
    console.log("Start Main Script" + " at " + seconds + ":" + milliseconds);
    (function() {
        var jQueryLoading = setInterval(function() {
            var date = new Date();
            var seconds = date.getSeconds();
            var milliseconds = date.getMilliseconds();
            console.log("Waiting for jQuery" + " at " + seconds + ":" + milliseconds);
            if (typeof($) === "function") {
                clearInterval(jQueryLoading);
                var date = new Date();
                var seconds = date.getSeconds();
                var milliseconds = date.getMilliseconds();
                console.log("jQuery Loaded" + " at " + seconds + ":" + milliseconds);
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var date = new Date();
                    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
                    var milliseconds = date.getMilliseconds();
                    console.log("Document Ready" + " at " + seconds + ":" + milliseconds);

                    $(".button").button();
                    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
                    $("#tabs,#tabsB,#tabsC").tabs();

                    var date = new Date();
                    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
                    var milliseconds = date.getMilliseconds();
                    console.log("END Document Ready" + " at " + seconds + ":" + milliseconds);
                });
            }
        }, 100);
    })();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);">Random Button</a>
<br>
<input class="datepicker" type="text">
<br>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Nothing important here.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Nothing important here.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Nothing important here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="tabsB">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabsB-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabsB-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabsB-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabsB-1">
    <p>Nothing important here.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabsB-2">
    <p>Nothing important here.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabsB-3">
    <p>Nothing important here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="tabsC">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabsC-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabsC-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabsC-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabsC-1">
    <p>Nothing important here.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabsC-2">
    <p>Nothing important here.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabsC-3">
    <p>Nothing important here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMEA7VE2jC1Dy1vuR3lHcbd1SbpLlmON3azGTlqrX6K8uEAFAGoQ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQwNa_aeXvCr9cUEY4aya_ge94eVvp3SQW2cgxovAmhQeBLqGlMgw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvbnXTt-76LlTsIqMhQJNhwSNBfAc0m-RTXePqPmYN9JvLtVMj8A'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTLwjhoyIYvPRAE_2ohFr-ModePUw2qC5I2zmBR57scDLxfwm1vtQ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRuezcCEbBuzHVZuEZIfkoyBf_MkttrfjmE4O1PmY_WyAk-_qEK'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQsDlhL1536dgX_tjYtsd19eLIjZIPRkhyYt3WBJP4G4xJyEnNVg'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRXn4_v167XtiDVsdVqYAjQ5d6jJg8oS7MlaruTIicQ8qL3J4DS'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSyYnrY_vniHRWuZTU_BAssDWACltIHRlEJopRrxO24i2ekW7uH'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTL-6XDiTPfYr-wGcv9faYi18-IllqGtk_frDfMqZ1HqSWlIBDR'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTF2S6ksbGsl-HPPIthnnZeayDIteqc7BF5EMWbo0hYMislfAIdTA'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTAfMMXMQZyjtMAnPaSoXrMPcS4X0eX3s4cCSo2SfDFlfO-vSaM'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS4tqET6kA3p5Dzu8OpJ810i2cfBnPLZkqXJtODf7ZFpfdfJgW6PA'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ7TjBEwK_ff1_x2TdIS0IVBmsjOj2pIFs5sp6reV0hYMNbzWKq'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSDjFqcIq85bqUC5nYYlZ1piLEj06hMmzKwjr9z6QT6OqEUAYgl'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMjlsUuwGNP7Ga8BZHjw74nuA4g9s_gZmivynahlnoZ9WN2lW8'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQoiQBnlcL8uFlnOnp1byq5mQDvYOfEe7GK9fg_59a59GfnTX6cSA'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZjo8wMHTCyCH5ZpO2xBtcQ1Gg9hHg8brubEkF-rRsAtbSw9lE'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScFkaXP6gzao4fPgHquwjl7fPOtJ5WcwWppCkuGZSusMMacJtG'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRuusir5bEcM7ljLFRu9iUFjxv63edpP0JakCkrAfTrOuIDGIOnRw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQPc_4MzJ2tKfNrix7OUEvHGxSZNaMulv2PidvJqNsfgVt434ItOQ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9-iKLUHqe8Lu24GLglK4AoeljJehx2i9F-FTwUdDUkazmZ0On'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTFQuHFEKif0oL2bzFRzRvccM7--7KCFuP_Uzus4vqq_15a7Q3Pg'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSTPXt_GMtZyt_TaNZWSUowXnImYDKyQzprW-pwp52M8S00McQ2'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSTFLOY1XoHRwnYsJE9RObslzB4QkldzgxtUkAtX0oFXPzOQEvv'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScm6DEnYeG0JXGmnDSV8GiK-r7YDvTTt1qogVDrnM3GwH3moLZ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYvTr0vmrt-tq23MzCxQ2w87WMaxX9ULWZPGEfbXjGyktZJooK'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYvkT4xQWcrV1v6ItNtFYxGxpH8hUVcM3hIWfNN5qiFGpVO1vv2g'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTrCa3FJr7JvUeSBvsdfbIZw3nkk-IQXZ0umNpWshcG4oa3bbC3'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6uDkmQ7535tCSJRaucm0FwKGwAeN0pXb8svhPm_1OrM5GRJiT'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsxHTS8dLnjW8_gxo0UcoAPfWZNN3SuDrY3CFL0vGX-iDaArAq'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRO0epZo0U1W_AZDj_Hg-hNSXopWjHk-Kg7E0Uj3UBodlVZyVdp'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRWc4Do-nSR30PTStY-kV58iFRF9-n-t4WnwrREXqfC6Q_ObfI7'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMAbF3BQeZkpYdJoINe5eRIUeDaJFyR_QrKDUXmogMj9oSrPjX'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQOOiYJimxXO8h0V2gzRn9QYPGGm4wa4xBgBri2ikP1NaSmkk4b'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR3nZ0cSJ1hx0zp2jPI85sWDW4A7xBMKul_qBWF3TZrt0KjVSJIUg'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSRE8mwAB-OdOVIKZJqziQNu81lw3PlfBjoWuDHDKYVSCdBjSdutQ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMfCp8OrQZUVM-gWiMA7jus84MzLasoInPgkGB-TPiSFWXHfLZrg'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHKh1Dl0sKW9sUIhO2FPwcRcTu-O5aLL1clYmM_qkB81kfjch1'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS9jC3HxonImAcLewFa-LP4SFjiSjJyLRP0ZLWdua6H7hTrOqA8'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT6Q-WFFlIssPoYKHXRtFva_sJX0nLXHJ27Yms2qmLJD5c1TVYNEQ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTLNQedHYOVBqfROc1wgGU90DpIjb96bbsp6QaxY0mTlFTHDbk'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ66-T6Xw4sZr-AVC9ZS8ZnvWZ5qLKW2Y2_tvOORRREeta52wDj7g'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQU5j7IRyrFiLaOHwUtvT5P1DbEZIZFvTY-vzhDVxJRTsP1iducxg'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRlK3ORdmT2YebqqVzEUUIcx9-zIdzsFrEuFdLVqkKPDgR2Ggh9nQ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTipcSG-ZnjXyketRQMT7Lq8TSefRLo_6tIG_P6m0ke0oKLl-t'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHQeMxpPMfxLhLNFQVu-vm5ihgcxsxCoZvn4BtzzFLZsERFwcC'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfxzxTigHZNvRdoQ_4pTEn9gmxpgUHCC18t1Dgf8YffJHjln4L8Q'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdEK2xJjDo4-u7XW6FrFTMeeZ7mSCpvIl3FkPV8SRTsA9iRPiQyA'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTTXWYU7gees2U91fqsc2DCfVuyeX7yAH3BKBV46KZDK88etY8HBA'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRxVgUaIFMbzfqsNxVChg7duVXMP2tXhYCjGw3pOrqkAqZuQvS0gQ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSuypwnxbybSGUHwAGSniCJpfdL3hUdV6YRRnoEStXek2Mmh1kX9Q'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsIETbTjbvPCSRzXk1La3IJVmQyQAbz1TmGbkYzEYNIurl9Wkq'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQMRQSurNXZHTl1gD2DYwH_SOOEx2dHkYlLvpQrFENRX37_6oWV'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRxjgZ0Eix2uMYSJiYMG54v0ElTenzQO0Zb-tsVFs7s3fEckcJ3Og'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ8uRsbdqb3gCI15huW6lRTGbFnEh8vczQRtSARDnyihQ_Lrfs-0g'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRfSMTKB0NsRANvym9RsPtgTG1wHlHagclDHcxUaqEe7qrFxX4K'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRtPLvQabo5ExMY55osAyEsPwe67BxEv7WbN-oqH78kUKoNObUYug'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTch5fcpcQ9YiojQGW1N3JDDx-_ORkty_ENu_nt2x6fdQKmApMY'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnD302ll4sVYNXChck9SxWP9PMYBfVAyH7rJGtYyvU1nCQ3QZN'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ3wJqfgPZJ115lkQW2brPUQdhG8mH7q0iKbsibchxfcEglIn_M'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRHJNk5oRzvIU07QvuO4axUbrORdvJrJ7ig62_KugTDQuU5PD95HQ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQVbsBbYYZKoMooSZnx2vUqfoc8w2FSSN4Mh_97sHNDQDWf-XIWgw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSmf3k46WXJjuVS-FVd6Z24YkxNcFltnGCRiYR1yIh5fuuwvPCY4g'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSag2huowBOzkk3wc7EH-Q-J_zcuRjywowNW-n1wLss9xzNQh6tUA'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTa22kezM8k2WVS6vklBBU9CEsBszTwmYSmUbGaVxQuxEovlDCE'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ4mKjQqVqbZk4q_nDOsaQpoEwjdExycpQEOAxcUmDWvbLRbhjc'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTzlI4AzI_SG5kECCwz9gTyg-dOqJz4h1q8ljVZh1sxv2cUrYQR'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTgXmmsyq4QTl0I4nsgaClYuhWLZ8Yc_6WNjkRqY-FKzylwOFus'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRAtwCft1-RbzMh3SVgVyBePGHQwClRfYAbbun3JN7COExiZ_Zi'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYAPTHrdLxS-707k1KJftA42-_X98LTxc7zgzen4sohlADTsAI'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTNfNgfBxmxEfBqDSrfAzDBLmwt09KTqfT30w3pRCC8Z1_Phrcw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSWDAsqVEi-QyH-UU8O7HbOe6fLAHM3QecmuzyCMhVGtDvvKOBudw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTJIQkoSu-YmXNBghR8mKFTETOhbWsZVWRiEeGVUg_LMp6YNWKfzw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZnyuyZkufzUOKTXXB4yxKTWBdDj4iyD6QB0qrLUzanHXz2o1MMA'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ99uPq2smPBsr5Ka2HYMka8N3q-Nuybrt-kGHF4GpIj8w1dJI'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTEhH5iTqqXVWwrCOJxJd1NJbGUY_jRSnE3y1ySjuxUthZoWerQ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRcFEk5SxjgbQn7gkLQrNWOVS_dQKbi_5m_I773R7A6YRvXDcDVYg'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQqvm7S_7yPo5rv_xqSvBQqRnX_Ztw7J4FnMZ0VS7N4xR5Gnnd-CA'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSofhozdsxOqULCOTNG2O2HkPtWBJhKWJCTi395r11fH8yuR833'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSY0rdoBpspZFp_fZSJryoa-McUmXboyfQWnjLm6bEtVOXpZNYPIA'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSysBEG7D3y76k1pkc2unNzB7S0fPZQvJpV-_rTyAkQ6qV4WTwJmQ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTWVFSFAHlbQhD8f6wMOumpN4D61ymEGmZ0ZVwbMuMY_s0u9IOb'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTS9l44EgR1oWycXLPRsQ_S_zN_6vmnc2DcrOzDIP-GmxNi7w7LSg'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRamONreqLyG2_iVR2cYyQF7l2P9lW89iuwbjHN_WlIoEVZoKQw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTgYsGzEHeSu0_HGPdBu04IyQJm_YeOSBKwR4iZb7roPhgZEjD5cg'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRm1mfJxYNPK6Lxczm9SvhPyP626pEZknheUg_7uKN0p_dFnT7FrQ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRJnRPNrxUskGmuB9NhJCGT_1jy4YNoMW4TZ4Kg-iPQ0_HLmK7piw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSIiOWMgn-pNtwYU-izl3vL092jsgWNCjzs852BfdACtuy1cTgIzw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTZA2H0geMe0PTY6-biryf0qgHRGa62c0JXY7KtCEEmkQnaFw-gbw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRdruiExqEpSS5r_-9fdZjxxWQxm9kQUZ9jMh_EEHpVvUiGwrXjpw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRVGt9aeOhncIuwqh77dkkHgTKN6q6Ms_n0faN0sDUP_PO71MW_jQ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQUz37kRGUsISXZXFW7sXNFtqViU4XOjQcwcCK5eZ5YWqR9CKhAxg'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR5CoF7Ogp1SJ3xpAY_HOCDu-vZaoLBxQf8hJnc6WLcSxgdXLaa'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTlqodrzjraH6AKtup9YF8AIPCUUHo93Fb4lX6XixSHrczatm1gPA'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTrN38pC_dicbgR3Wg2QbE3qJF3E6INqxv8LegFKcHzhraewSB-'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYj7t6ceADy7jRbFbtOv_B-_xJOOkzy1yOTo1DQBRuMELFXKiB'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTLVvT6DJXoDVtX1nnwTxcIsgtXQ_dwv4Kbgc4d5-rPy0y0xurt'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYdCGewAC_YD3q3aEDEk6Xl1PmaD0pdvn-b6Fa3xuzksk9th1K'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZ8eTgeuisaqbLEA5325de5wA_TlHAfrNXD8ywdJY5r5drzSJMDw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQsGvhEwZWqhEOg1GnrLsttBF3wzG5sx0ClTrs1KVpj6kD05YjK'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTE-ZidZMQZ7VH-OE1vxhnSo5yytgvgmUChQR3M04fpiA3yYNCaJQ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTQiKtXKVz3oPH9PucWKeeUDvwVfIW2Cv324AFabnTP6yPc_eMV5g'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT58GXbsA1kqm9HjyDBrxY2NcxeserFd3iMQXI11Bu-rmWLzG6G'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSs9W5DXA1o92wsk6Q__fDuwCa84YVXMD5DmxEAKxvMD92UeyOT'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTly1TDUG-uMBzBplRohjQZQc__iTMOQ4UucwHMyb0D_QRdAVLe'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS-WY_RkUb19vqZybcOkhV5b_VfAsberuN6DxAv6DOlHHTY49v5'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT21ufd3BKm1_JJWg7EksnJJWxPllpuK36fWZ_iDYP7lJVlU6C5'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRSJgftKRhz8FmWbV-zbDWuNdJr5cMGmPwZvhHyuMq6_0Tq9mG_'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS19qg5CCnozhnVwxxRNK0o5Kjp3AOlqU_jxSD36IVrFKMsSZQr5g'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSxtX4dX8jeqmcmdRHmkaVZoQEFcR5zKIjAStnx6DhxZo2n0x6GaQ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTb_1lRdfGmDBV1wL1J-VkLbONroacX1RYd8a7uJYnV3aVI2KRN'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ4rrkemcbtT4PuSrm-rA2adB7vXj6xoANxJ_6ug0CocVyB2Bir'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTWjGfbGcs5hFr2IMd6xCjCR7sYEK47cq4JdAOl5KSf2V6c5-AnRw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTDRBHV7U1xcaiDVG-D_GhxQ6VU7dxqJd3OpkiSj5HNo6dz46Ob8Q'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRXslTqC-xneGPh225sxSpptK-AOrNaXChaBGjDZlIcdGV2Y_rJNg'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQK-jk8r8-Qo81XirlpYUXkCWZVR1qD0Llg3mqzP2wJgSx4lJF8'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQrD3CvsEOwHHbypN0eYvIa42OKB7swAvGmFTGchWwXRzFLgkcUMw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ5uSXr11mV5ZjBDLlF0B1Pc5AivT7Uf9Z-Y6kv3pT9SZyJCQRs'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRFBa6Q7VCjjW4-_utX17LgYx8TgI4BO2y5c7iQYwqit-BHcTud9g'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTFK0I-a35RjJSFVqJMkiEW7p7tkeF7T_e1cx6e61gkRuFvQHT9PA'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYGjV-Lk3uG1jbaeKLeHbkvT8DhD8UK1mcy65dxfwvEgMdFpXBmA'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTJl8cgcO5yctNr8s6hTW8CV0uizUJe__4nLV_G0Q5HICUks1-e'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQb6loAhh6uBXf9IuOkmOCCyImpyTRjxawz8vj0OvZzpP4Lh51Hfw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhcjLjZW1snP6h_V0JepiF4rX5ErPqY0BAD3fq9ns3C5MUHMEp'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTp_OtenEKiGi8UaVwuYlle1Cy3z2RwvnHdMuAyN6qXwAEkq1Wskw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQJ7cemlPUe1swuO9ucSH_J8ulSwAqBHABhgqbfodCRIeG1EyjPtA'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTlXdtMDHqq6DeGD-PqIGoIEeHlCL4yiWScfZsrqfgGZHe0p4awCw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQDSAGjuFvjZ6OKjxgj-yCKuy0c8jD-uJ6SXJG3jhKm0SA7q5VnGQ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSuKYQtApKkm7N_owQVntbWCIWTZc-GGT3z151dBd1rgKfKcSa6rA'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTrWYTsazZYcmn1IT3AE_qyHpsMG8K8WdtYcJYjRu8B2ahECEg9tg'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTyecjUx45_ZAteXQ6-EBBS82ctk3eyXH6N1eQBi3SBT5EZSdZLag'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRtFQPAEVOi5SF6PURTAdmvzclgBgOb-gy9w7RXTv8t869EKs4dyA'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSswmg9LN5Y1zHPSpE3_O2tsoTQ8jjM8xdXxMzqwzQrz-LGH_mc'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSA-S1NjtQ1Z7fiw8MLS-f6esWRHREDVPCz-ICMDL86mmkMVVJBVw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTK-nYwmZJm6KYGkQvlyPv5CuCFK_Ddisy5p__T4kJMkP13ZDLB'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTJqpiLO_DVRB6JJpo8WrBLjYF_merYO3dIkOtCLYRfxMiUiupD'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRSUVSgHtO3Aj6AdxPmMojal-gIJYF5MrWOaVFrvHQhyqmbmQ_l'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnGDqo3rExtwa7ADW5MvmEwd2Ok_DZYcguZGa9pFMRBx1jVXOT'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnmnaCieqXd9cjq7d8A1i1x9hVEZ14fL4hPrJqfL8O3qdGx3FD'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQa3-2htYvY4R0UAtHwDPBqKLy_dkI7ZGmT4rbivSFv2P6zgVYC'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZW7jHdZE57oNzLtIbAZJtCztxH4z-MRyZX9hUR7FQ2eWnnneF'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQqYy1H3lFd84UifTtFMnpwHhJaQAHYupu8_Q7S4xZxKeipW2peUg'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTULufCJ9Opo3eaybKnxaxX2OuKHTEpJ93nDjJsCl3m0WnBtvigKA'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSPE-Mmnl8tQUp7eJ2TxfLLEkXEx9tPgn8lkCszxTKPWVQ0Hgg_xw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRgjAk_Bm4_XYiQXuSb7OKEpRB0get0myYdsuiNCVT8R6g89qApEQ'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_7S6CEkUxmRLp2dAPNGf8RALiqio27IFckL_B87Y03-ZTAXZw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRPtP4VYdA88rFkcd_ffOPMxqvZJg7tbpgKfIc5wV9zOs8Ogd-Oag'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRv-dFfXzRpyRZIlJ4zvucgOWxPQU8JgjAg-uOzhVBf0cK8CR0rXw'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTTEnrYpjdo_dv1-LFnfXgd3cZQHLg3p7Rv4rfaWqTehUdNhJat'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTe2OqTpbTeF2eq5Yh5gA17c9m-j8l4K7zBvCJhaFr27aBOcmIX3g'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSP3xnoY6TH7OPufR8hMrJrbO4ZslfZiySaDndraMMWWzSsRExU'>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnL9OO83__45B7CPAv2n8sSjf27t-N2vSbwDknBiB9loUsKHOdIw'>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    var milliseconds = date.getMilliseconds();
    console.log("End Page Load" + " at " + seconds + ":" + milliseconds);
</script>
```

Comment: if you want jquery to load faster, why don't you download a minified copy onto your server instead of loading it from the internet every time, and load the images async?

Comment: Why would it load any faster from my server than from google? Loading it from google has the benefit of possibly already being cached.

Comment: Are you using both `async defer` on same script tag? Sounds like you want to use async, not defer

Comment: @MikeWillis yes. it's already loading your page from the server, adding another 83 kb (for 2.1.1 minified) will not be a noticeable load on your server. I don't know a ton about how scripts are loaded via the `src` attribute, but the browser will have to make a separate request to retrieve it, instead of it being wrapped in one response from your server.

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, I'm following some advice from this blog post: https://www.igvita.com/2014/05/20/script-injected-async-scripts-considered-harmful/

Comment: @DLeh I could bundle jQuery and jQuery UI into my own script, which would only be one call to an external source instead of three, and wouldn't be a bad alternative. I wouldn't inline any of them. Regardless, I'm still curious about the question I posted.

Comment: @MikeWillis Makes sense then but this way i guess this is the defer attribute which is used on modern browsers which support both type attributes. Try just using async (even `Async attribute makes no guarantees about execution order`) just for testing purpose.

Comment: @A.Wolff OK I just tried it, no real difference though. Ran three or four tests and each of them had just about the same result.

Comment: I'd recommend using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to watch the HTTP request response traffic from your browser. Based on your metrics it does indeed look like its waiting for the images to load. Also, [here's another great read on script loading you may find interesting.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/)

Comment: @BrandonBoone Thanks Brandon, I had read that post about script loading a few weeks ago, it was interesting. I never tried fiddler, gave it a shot just now, it confirmed what I had seen using the console and network traffic - jQuery and jQuery UI are requested very early, and they just wait a while to run doc ready. So the questions remain - why does it happen this way when they're loaded asynchronously, and is there a way to improve it?